# Ajax Controls are not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, windows-8

I am working on asp.net. I have developed one website and it is working fine. But there is one client's PC where the website is not working properly.

The main problem is with some of the AJAX controls. The two controls which are not working are Accordion Pane and Model Popup.

I saw the developer option of the browser and its states the following error/warning while I am visiting that page.

****InterYield Click Bind version 1.0-SNAPSHOT.4,685 20131123-0125 clickbinder.do?ver=1.0-SNAPSHOT.4%2C685:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL xdm.html:8
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. init2.js:1
InterYield click bind handler had no ad coverage. nocoverage.do?callback=InterYieldNS.NoCoverage&product=iy&title=&matchedKeyword=&affiliate=adpeak2&…:6
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://telemetry.scorpionsaver.com/te.aspx?callback=jQuery18308800485304091…22%3A%22about+to+call+server%22%2C%22sampleRate%22%3A10%7D&_=1386416017076". 
jquery.min.js:2
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <****

The website is deployed on .net 2 framework. The client is using windows 8 operating system.

I have checked three browsers on clients pc. IE, Chrome and Firfox. but the problem exists on all 3 browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I work with a couple of different websites that have users with a similar issue, where nothing loads past a certain point.  The only thing similar with all the users is the InterYield Click Bind in their Console logging.
I had them run a Malware scanner (Malwarebytes Anti-Malware works best), and after it cleans the system, they are able to access the sites.

Hope this helps!